# Populating Drop down dynamically using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In one of my form there were two Dropdown fields. The second dropdown has to be populated from the database, dynamically from the selection of first dropdown.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi karthik, posting the screenshot of the UI gives no insight to what you trying to achieve or what you have already tried... Try explaining more.

Comment: hi @loxxy i do not how to begin as i have told im beginner trying to learn it googled it for so much time did not able to find, so i felt would get some help here

Answer (score 3):

In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the first `DropDownList`, add code to populate the second `DropDownList` based on the selected value of the first list

Like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="from" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="from_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="to" />

    protected void from_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = this.from.SelectedValue;

        this.to.DataSource = /*get the data of the second list based on: selectedValue*/;
        this.to.DataBind();
    }
```